# Product collection filter by Downloadable Information

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, collection

I want to get a product collection with fillers(Downloadable Information link, URL).

My current code is below.

```
$pcollection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('gt' => $last_extract))
->setOrder('product_id','ASC')
->setPageSize(2);
```

I want to like below :

```
$pcollection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('gt' => $last_extract))
->addAttributeToFilter('download_link', ['like' => '%.zip%'])
->setOrder('product_id','ASC')
->setPageSize(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try to do it in 2 steps as the information you need about the download link is not in your product collection. Please try

```
        $pcollection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('gt' => $last_extract))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', \Magento\Downloadable\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_DOWNLOADABLE)
        ->setOrder('product_id', 'ASC')
        ->setPageSize(2);

    $products = [];
    foreach ($pcollection as $product) {
        $links = $product->getTypeInstance()->getLinks($product);
        foreach ($links as $item) {
            $linkFile = $item->getLinkFile();
            $extension = pathinfo($linkFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if ($extension === 'zip') {
                $products[] = $product;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $products;
```